# Image in HTML title tag but not a favicon

Tags: html, title, favicon, emoji

I know how to use a favicon but I mean something else: There must be a way to use images in html title tags see this page as an example: http://helios.io/

How is this little rockets right of the title text added?

Comment: Look at their source : <title>Helios </title>

Comment: yes i see the square but what is this? some utf-8 char or something else?

Comment: Yes it is. It's a little rocket.

Comment: Thank you but I only see an empty square. Could you give me the char code or at least point me to a side where I can find more "UTF8 image chars"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use images in a title, not in the traditional sense of JPG, PNG, GIF, etc.

The little rocket ship that you see is a text character that can be 'typed'.   There are numerous little characters you can type that way.

However, I believe the rocket ship you see is a Mac / iOS only character...  as it's an emoji rocket ship.